# Missing digits in magento Price on frontend

Tags: php, magento

Im using the following code to include the price for my products on a custom page:

```
<?php echo Mage::helper('tax')->getPrice($_product, $_product->getFinalPrice(), null);?>
```

the price shows up on the frontend as it should apart from under one instance. That being if the product price ends in a zero (or 2) within the decimal places so for example a price of £3.00 will be displayed as £3, £3.50 will be displayed as £3.5 & £3.99 will display as is.

Is there a better way for me to pull the product price?

Comment: whats wrong with that? in english terms that makes more sense to output like that.

Comment: in English terms… because i would like all the content to be fluent. To elaborate it acts upon single decimals too so £3.50 would be £3.5 which is not clean

Answer (score 0):

The price should be called as a float, but perhaps it's a data conversion issue from the DB?  Can you force that column to be a float field so that the DB stores the two decimal places as well?  Maybe make it FLOAT(7,2)?

Answer (score 0):

OK found the solution using the following code:

```
<?php echo number_format($_product->getPrice(), '2', '.', ',');?>
```